# Android Debugger Does not Attach

Tags: android, debugging

Waiting for Debugger ...

LogCat

Android Runtime Registering Native Function
Ignoring Second Debugger  Accepting and Dropping
Debugger has Detached
ActivityManager Unstilling process (for the application)

No Error messages
However a warning
Resource does not contain a package for resource 0xFFIIIOOS
Dialog Waiting for Debugger never leaves.  10 + minutes.

Don't see the error in the Log, so really tough to see what this might be.
What should one do when seeing this attach debugger error?

Comment: I did find the problem.  It was a request requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); placed just below setContent().

Comment: window features must be requested before setContent() is called in the Activity.

Answer (score 17):

This can also happen by having two (or more) instances of Eclipse open.

Comment: If you've been trying out android development IntelliJ IDEA, then this can also happen if you have both Eclipse and IntelliJ open at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

After trying to

- restart the phone
- restart Eclipse
- kill the adb process and restart
- find out is there any process using the debug port 8600

problam still unsolved

finally I just disable and enable the `USB Debugging` option in `Developer options`, it works.

Comment: disabling and enablling `USB Debugging` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

this happens when the process crashes.  Look carefully in the LogCat for the source error.  You will find it.  So debugger does not attach because the process for the application has crashed, so there is nothing to attach to.

Comment: Well, the IDE tells me that it is connected to the device and LogCat is empty. So, your statement is not always true.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an odd case, but I use IntelliJ IDEA sometimes at the same time as Android Studio, and sometimes IntelliJ's debugger binds to the same port.. you can check by going to your command line and typing `lsof -i :8600` unless you've changed the default port number. this will show you what processes are using that port.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was running both IDEA and Android Studio and shutting down IDEA indeed helped solve the issue.

Comment: @znovotny excellent! glad I could help you solve this. It was driving me crazy for a while before I figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions presented here worked. In the end, I simply deleted all the project files from disk, did a checkout and imported the gradle based project again in Android Studio. After this, everything started to work again. It seems that there is an another Android Studio + gradle bug that is not obvious at all.

Answer (score 0):

Initial Steps :

1) adb kill-server and then adb start-server

or

2) USB debugging make it off then again On.

or

3) Clean build and then deploy

or

4) Device restart

if above did not work then see below :

Please check either You are not in release build.
if you are in debug build then in debug buildTypes "minifyEnabled" is false